# Are properties defined in constructor function own or inherited?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript sorry if this sounds as an easy question.
If I have following constructor function:

```
function Person(x,y){
 this.name = x;
 this.surname = y;

}
```

I am curious whether properties `name` and `surname` are considered *own* properties of objects of type `Person` or *inherited*?

e.g.

```
var x = new Person("John", "Doe");
```

I did some tests using `hasOwnProperty` which suggest they are considered own properties rather than inherited, just wanted to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are *own* properties. When instantiating an object with `new Person`, an object will be created, your function `Person` will be called, and `this` inside `Person` refers to this new object. You're then explicitly directly setting properties on this object. In essence, no different than this:

```
function person(obj) {
    obj.name = 'Foo';
    obj.surname = 'Bar';
}

var o = {};
person(o);

o.name  // Foo
```

Comment: But if I define property via prototype - then it is considered inherited? (e.g. Person.prototype.age=9)

Comment: Stuff on `Person.prototype`, *not* set directly on `this` within the constructor, is indeed *inherited* and shared among all instances of `Person`.

Comment: stuff inside constructor function is also shared, e.g. if you hard code and assign some value to property, but I see, seems w.r.t to inheritance and own properties, this is distinction between function constructor and prototypes

Comment: You'd have to show some specific example of where you think something in a constructor is shared; generally speaking it's not.

Comment: By shared I mean any object you create with that function will have property set to a value specified in the constructor function (granted you assign some constant to property), e.g. function Person(){this.name="hi"}

Comment: Yes, but each instance will have their own version of that value. Try assigning an array (`this.foo = []`) and then mutate it (`o.foo.push('bar')`). Try this using the constructor, and the prototype. Instantiate a bunch of objects using either technique. Now you see what's shared and what's not.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, I will test it later. I was merely meaning value assigned will be shared (e.g. each person will have value "hi" in example of my above comment), you mean, the property itself is shared

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you to check this is to just try it and see.

But yes, they are considered *own* properties. Inside the constructor function, `this` is a reference to the newly constructed object (when `Person` is called with `new`).

It's essentially the same thing as doing

```js
var x = {};
x.name = 'foo'
console.log(x.hasOwnProperty('name')); // true
```

Compare that to a prototype property:

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.brain = 'meat-like';

var p = new Person('Bob');

console.log(p.name);  // Bob
console.log(p.brain); // meat-like

console.log(p.hasOwnProperty('name'));  // true
console.log(p.hasOwnProperty('brain')); // false
```